# libtorrent alerts - read_piece_alert

Tags: libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I have a multi-file torrent (3 files). I subscribed to read_piece_alert as explained [here](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Alerts.html#alert).

```
std::vector<alert*> alerts;
ses.pop_alerts(&alerts);
for (alert* i : alerts) {
        switch (a->type()) {

                case read_piece_alert::alert_type:
                {
                        read_piece_alert* p = (read_piece_alert*)a;
                        if (p->ec) {
                                // read_piece failed
                                break;
                        }
                        // use p
                        break;
                }
                case file_renamed_alert::alert_type:
                {
                        // etc...
                }
        }
}
```

How can I know to which file the piece belongs in the multi-file torrent?

For example my multi-file torrent has an .AVI, .TXT and .JPG. Is there some kind of index to know to which file the piece actually belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can map a piece-index into one or more file-indices + offsets with the `map_block()` function on `file_storage`. See the [documentation](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Storage.html#map_block()).